# Can I enforce required fields when creating a node programmatically?

Tags: nodes

I'm experimenting with creating content. I made a method to create a piece of example content and redirect to its edit page. I didn't set some fields that I had defined as required on the content type. I thought it would probably cause an exception, or at least generally not work, but it created the node without the required fields.

Is there a way to prevent a node from saving if any of its required fields are empty? I've read some about [entity validation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/entity-validation-api-overview) and started working with that a bit, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already some built-in setting or something that does that. If there isn't, is a validator the way to go?

```
class ExampleController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function create_example_content()
    {
        $node = Node::create(['type' => 'example_type']);
        $node->set('title', 'Example Content');
        $node->save();
        return $this->redirect('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $node->id()]);
    }
}
```

I did notice that not setting the title causes an SQL error, but it looks like that's different because the title is a column in the node record rather than a related field.

The redirect to the edit form is done just to debug the code and check the result of creating the node.

Comment: What is wrong with `$node->validate()` described in the linked documentation? Also I'm not quite sure about the use case why you save the node instead of returning an entity form with the unsaved node `return $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($node);`, so that if the form is abandoned without submitting you don't get useless node entries.

Comment: @4k4 oh, nothing's wrong with it, I just didn't realize it would work if I hadn't defined a validator. And for now I'm just using this to generate some specific example content after a fresh installation of a module I'm working on. I'm redirecting to the edit form to check the result of creating it.

Comment: Drupal core has validators for entities. It's not required the module defines a validator.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks. Now that you've said it, that seems much more obvious. I feel silly for asking this.

Comment: It's not a silly question at all. There are many cases where a module is also supposed to implement a different hook/class/method for something to work.